# concatenation of regular and DCFL

Tags: regular-languages

$S -> AB$

$A -> aA / epsilon$

$B ->aBb / epsilon$

What is the class of language generated by the above grammar ?

I think that it generates $a^* a^n b^n |  n>=0$ so it should be regular as regular is concatenated with DCFL which is able generate epsilon. But the answer is CFL .

I think that answer would be CFL if n would have been greater than equal to 1 and not 0

Can someone please point out my mistake ?

Comment: It seems that $L = \{ a^* a^n b^n \} = \{ a^m b^n \mid m \geq n \}$ which is .... In other words the implication $R \in Reg, C \in CFL, \epsilon \in C  \Rightarrow R \cdot C \in Reg$ is wrong. You cannot say that if $C$ can generate $\epsilon$ then $R \cdot C \in Reg$; you must consider ALL strings that can be generated both by $R$ and $C$.

Comment: This answer also uses similar logic to prove that language is regular https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649335/403592. I am not understanding the difference between n>=0 and n>=1. How will that change the answer ? @Vor.

Comment: Here is one more link which says L1.L2 is regular if L1 is regular and L2 is non regular containing epsilon. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298201/concatenation-of-finite-languages-and-regular-languages

Comment: Read both questions carefully ... they doesn't prove what you say. For example in the first question they assume that  $B = \Sigma^*$, in the second question they assume that $L_1 = \Sigma^*$. And in the third case they use $L_1 = \{a^m b^n \mid m \neq n$ which, if prefixed with $a^*$, can generate $\Sigma^*$ which is regular.

Comment: In 2nd question we are getting it as regular because we can subsitute n as 0. Why can't we subsitute n as 0 here?

Comment: Where (the hell :-) do you read "... we can substitute $n$ as $0$ ..."? I only see that $a^n b^n$ which are the only excluded strings not in $L_2$ are generated in the concatenation with $ a \cdot a^{n-1} b^n$ ... leading to $L_1 \cdot L_2 = \Sigma^*$ which is regular

Comment: Because only if we put n=0,  0^n 1^n vanishes and we get sigma * which is regular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67613/discussion-between-vor-and-rajesh-r).

Comment: So sigma * concatenated with any language is always regular right ?

Comment: No, it is true if the concatenated language can generate $\epsilon$; theorem: $L_1 = \Sigma^*, \epsilon \in L_2 \Rightarrow L_1 \cdot L_2 \in Reg$ (try to prove it). Otherwise it depends on $L_2$

Comment: Oh I get it. If it would have been (sigma *)( a^n b^n | n>=1) then it would have been DCFL right ? If it's n>=0 then regular.

Comment: Yes!!! (mmmm probably not DCFL, but surely CFL and surely not regular)